# Cakephp routing to alternative login screen

Tags: php, cakephp, routes

I have a CakePHP application and one of my clients wants its own login screen for their users. So when they login they see the logo of my clients' company.

I tried to solve this problem by adding a new route to `routes.php`:

```
Router::connect('/client', array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'loginclient', 'home'));
```

So they would be able to type businesslearning.nl/client to go to the login screen of their company.

In the `users_controllers.php` I copied the login action, changed its name into 'loginclient' and added a loginclient layout to it.

I also created a loginclient layout.

This looked a bit like overkill to me but I don't know of any other possibility to solve this.

And unfortunately it didn't work:

```
Error: The requested address '/client' was not found on this server.
```

Comment: can you set debug mode to 2? This way you can see the real error you are getting

Comment: which version of cakephp are you using?

Comment: Are you using Auth component? Maybe your loginclient action is not allowed.

Comment: Hi @skywalker your answer was the right one. Thanks! How can I mark it as an answer. I searched for it on Stackoverflow, but I see no V that I can click on.